# Integer roots to $ax^2 + bx + c$ and $(a+1)x^2 + (b+1)x + (c+1)$

Tags: roots, quadratics

Do there exist quadratic functions $ax^2 + bx + c$ and $(a+1)x^2 + (b+1)x + (c+1)$ with integer coefficients such that both have only integer roots?

---

I was thinking of taking the discriminant in an attempt to try and start off this proof, but I don't quite think it'd be a much use due to the condition that we need integer roots. Than, how exactly should I start this problem?

Comment: Why did you think the discriminant approach would not be of use? Set the discriminant equal to any perfect square $k$ and try to factorise using difference of squares and then write down all possible factor pairs. In fact, I believe that is the standard approach for such problems

Comment: note that since $s=r_1+r_2=-b/a$ and $p=r_1r_2=c/a$ are integers, then $a$ shall divide $b,c$ and $(a+1)$ shall divide $(b+1),(c+1)$, maybe we can start reducing the number of variables from this.

Comment: Does $a=0,b=1,c=0$ count? Or do you intend $a\neq 0$?

Comment: For non-zero $a$ you can choose $(a,b,c)=(-1,0,0)$ or for example $(-1,2,-1)$ .

Comment: @Sil But then $a+1=0$, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: Note also, for similar problems, since this has a solution which doesn't require it, charging the signs of $a,b,c$ and swapping the polynomials gives a second solution if a solution has been found. It is therefore possible to assume $a$ non-negative.

Comment: True, i was looking at these solutions but yea that idea seems wrong: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h530549p3028064, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h421073p2378216. Removed the comments to clear up, leaving the links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there does not (for $a\ne 0,-1$). We shall prove this with a simple parity argument.

One of $a, a+1$ must be even. For simplicity, suppose $a$ is even. The other case is similar.

Since $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has integer roots, it can be written as:

$$0=a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=ax^2-a(\alpha+\beta)x+a\alpha\beta=ax^2+bx+c$$

Hence $b$ and $c$ are both divisible by $a$, and hence are both even.

Now consider the other equation, $(a+1)x^2+(b+1)x+(c+1)=0$.

All three coefficients are odd, and in particular, $a+1$ and $c+1$ can only have odd factors.

<strike>If this equation indeed has integer roots, it can be factorized.</strike>

Considering cross method, or similar methods, we see that b+1 is a sum of two products of two odd numbers, which is even, and a contradiction. I intend to improve the rigour of this statement, if possible.

EDIT: we can make this rigourous using the root argument above, write:

$$0=(a+1)(x-\alpha')(x-\beta')=(a+1)x^2-(a+1)(\alpha'+\beta')x+(a+1)\alpha'\beta'$$

Since $c+1$ is odd, both $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$ are odd. This makes $\alpha'+\beta'$, and thus $b+1$, even.

Comment: Nicely done. The special case $a=0$ needs to be excluded.

Comment: Of course. I excluded it as this case and $a=-1$ would not form two quadratic equations.

Comment: @player3236 thanks for clearing the confusion, I have no idea why I thought that lol

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If $c=0$ then the equations are $x(ax+b)=0$ and $x((a+1)x + b+1)=0$, the solution sets of which are $\{0,-b/a\}$ and $\{0,-(b+1)/(a+1)\}$, respectively.</strike>

Taking $a=1$ and $b$ an odd integer $2k+1$ makes the solutions all integers since $b$ is divisible by $1$ and $b+1$ is divisible by $2$.

**EDIT:** Okay, now the question has been changed so this is not a correct solution.